# Histogram of TIMESTAMP

Tags: r, timestamp, histogram, scale

I have a data.frame with only one column in R. I get it with an SQL query from a database. In that database that column has TIMESTAMP as datatype. In R the data.frame has datatype "double"

```
typeof(MyTable$TimeLogs)
[1] "double"
```

The data looks like this (with over 800 rows):

```
2016-07-19 11:24:53
2016-07-19 11:24:58
2016-07-19 11:25:03
2016-07-19 11:25:09
...
2016-07-19 19:16:05
2016-07-19 19:16:35
2016-07-19 19:17:05
2016-07-19 19:17:35
2016-07-19 19:18:06
```

I want a histogram that shows how often a record was made between a certain "break-time". My statement in R is:

```
hist(MyTable$TimeLogs, breaks = "hours", 
    col="red", main = "Histogramm of 2016-07-19",  
    xlab = "Timestamp", ylab = "Frequency")
```

so I can see how many timelogs were made between 11:00:00 and 12:00:00 and so on... (or maybe within 30 min breaks). My Problem now is, that the histogram looks like this:

[Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsPq8.jpg)

as seen in the picture, the scale on the y-axis is quite confusing. It should go like from 2 to 50 (and not from 0.00000 to 0.00005). I guess it has something to do with the time/double-datatype of the TimeLogs. Any ideas how to put the scale right, or convert the data to the right format and still have a meaningful Y-Axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add freq=TRUE parameter to your hist call.

```
MyTable <- data.frame(TimeLogs=Sys.time()+round(rnorm(1000,5000,2500)))

hist(MyTable$TimeLogs, breaks = "hours", 
    col="red", main = "Histogramm of 2016-07-19",  
    xlab = "Timestamp", ylab = "Frequency",freq=TRUE)
```